# Maximizing the volume of a rectangular prism

Tags: geometry, optimization, contest-math

A rectangular prism has a surface area of $300$ square inches.  What whole number dimensions give the prism the greatest volume?

This is a math olympiad problem. It involves the volume and surface area of a prism.

Please, find a good solution.

Thank You!

Comment: This is a difficult problem.  If we begin with a right rectangular prism of dimensions $5\times 10\times 10$, and we sheer the $10\times 10$ sides into a parallelogram with an angle of $30^{\circ}$, we obtain a rectangular prism of surface area $300$ and volume $250$.  I believe this may be the maximum volume, although I haven't been able to prove it.

Comment: what is your definition of rectangular prism?

Comment: @wisefool: A solid with two parallel, congruent, rectangular faces, called bases, such that all cross sections parallel to the bases are congruent to the bases.  If we wanted to generalize even further, we could also consider parallelepipeds, which require that the bases be parallelograms.

Answer (score 2):

If we are assuming a fully rectangular prism---right angles all around---then there actually are only two candidates: $(h,w,l)=(20,5,2)$ and $(h,w,l)=(12,9,2)$. The former has a volume of 200, the latter has a volume of 216. So $(12,9,2)$ it is.

I solved this by exhaustive search. Here's my very dumb MATLAB code. Certainly it's not the most efficient but sometimes life calls for quick and dirty solutions. At least I limit the loops to 75, since the largest single dimension to achieve a surface area of 300 has to be less than that: $(75,1,1)$ gives us a surface area of 302:

```
for h = 1 : 75,
    for w = 1 : h,
        for l = 1 : w,
            if 2*(h*w+h*l+w*l) == 300,
                [h,w,l,h*w*l]
            end
        end
    end
end
```

So how would you do this without code? Well, I'd probably begin an exhaustive search, frankly, but with some efficiency. Let's rewrite the surface area formula as follows:
$$2(hw+hl+wl)=300 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad hw+l(w+h)=150
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad (h+l)(w+l)=150+l^2$$
So for a fixed value of $l$, $150+l^2$ must admit an integral factorization $pq$ with $p,q>l$.

- Consider $l=1$: we have $pq=151$. Since 151 is prime, so there are no
  solutions. Continuing:
- $l=2$, $pq=154$, prime factors 2, 7, and 11.
  Since $p,q>2$, our choices are $(p,q)\in\{(22,7),(14,11)\}$ or
  $(h,w,l)\in\{(20,5,2),(12,9,2)\}$. These are the two answers we found
  above.
- $l=3$: $pq=159$, prime factors 3 and 53; since $p,q>3$, there
  are no solutions.
- $l=4$: $pq=166$, prime factors 2 and 83; no
  solutions with $p,q>4$.
- $l=5$: $pq=175$, factors 5, 5, and 7. The only solution
  with $p,q>5$ is $(p,q)=(25,7)$, which gives us $(h,w,l)=(20,2,5)$, a
  permutation of our previous solution (and not even the optimal one, at that!).
- $l=6$: $pq=186$, factors 2, 3,
  31; no solutions with $p,q>6$.
- $l=7$: $pq=199$, prime, no solutions.

I could continue, but since this is a contest problem I probably would have taken a chance on $(12,9,2)$ pretty much as soon as I acquired it. Even if I had time I doubt I would have bothered to proceed past $l=4$ or $l=5$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I would like to see what the answer is in the case that we only require the bases to be rectangles and we allow the other sides to be parallelograms.  Or perhaps we allow all sides to be parallelograms.

Comment: That's a good question, but it is not the original question, agreed? (I understand you're the one that added the bounty though, so it's your prerogative!)

Comment: It depends on how you define rectangular prism (see my comment above).  Some would say you've considered *right* rectangular prisms.   In my definition above, which is not uncommon, sides can be parallelograms.  It is hard to tell what was originally intended.  See my first comment above for an example of a larger rectangular prism that is not right.

Comment: Actually I would say that the fact this was offered as a contest problem suggests that a right rectangular prism is what is intended. The more general case is significantly more difficult, as I am sure you would agree. In particular, where the right rectangular case is amenable to pencil & paper solution, I'm skeptical that would be the case for the more general problem.

Comment: Maybe you're right, and this is all that was intended.  I was hoping to find some clever and elegant way of solving the more general problem, something that could be done with pencil and paper for a contest.  So far I've had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

From various sources, https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m8f02/public_html/pauls_mws/boxeg.pdf
http://www.leadinglesson.com/problem-on-finding-the-rectangular-prism-of-maximal-volume

I confirmed that to obtain the max volume, the prism would be a cube.
So in this case, we would try to find the volume assuming that the prism is a cube.

1 Face of the cube would be 300/6=50

1 Side of the cube would be √50≈7.07

The volume would be 7.07 * 50 = 353.5

---

I know this answer is late, I found this because I was trying to find the answer to my homework. I am just a student in grade 8 so please correct me if I'm wrong.